# Android Periodic job scheduler not running after device reboot

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I have schedule a periodic Job which is as below :

```
    ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, MyJobService.class);
            JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
            builder.setBackoffCriteria(15*60*1000, JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR);
            builder.setPeriodic(15*60*1000);
            builder.setPersisted(true);
            builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
            sendToScheduler(context,builder);

  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private static  void sendToScheduler(Context context, JobInfo.Builder builder ){

        JobScheduler jobScheduler = null;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
        }else{
            jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        }
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.setPersisted(true).build());

    }
```

Its entry in manifest is as below :

```
<service
            android:name=".jobs.MyJobService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Below is JOB service code

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class MyJobService extends JobService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyJobService";


    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job started ************************************");

        //make network call and process data
        return true;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job ended -------------------------------");

        return true;

    }

}
```

After running this code on my one plus 6 device, I can see that this job is not running. I didnt get any logs for starting a job even after 15 -30 minutes on device reboot. I am not able to figure out whats the problem in the code

Comment: I hope this answer will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42084205/3816129

Comment: BOOT_COMPLETED doesn't work on one plus device due to battery optimization. Even if your request to ignore battery optimization it will skip the app for few minutes and add the app in battery optimization list